# VB WebMethod returning values, but jQuery autocomplete not displaying them

Tags: vb.net, jquery-autocomplete

I have a vb.net webpage with an asp textbox on it, and I'm trying to attach jquery autocomplete to that textbox. The debugger has shown me that typing in the textbox will call  the relevant webmethod in the code behind. That calls another method that uses linq-to-sql to get the results, then those results are returned, and then... Nothing. The VS debugger shows the correct results returned successfully from the webmethod, and the browser console doesn't show any errors, but the autocomplete never displays the suggestions.

What's happening to the suggestions between the code behind file and the jquery?

**autocomplete**

```
$(function () {
    $(".autoJobNum").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetCompletionList",
                data: "{'input':" + document.getElementById("<%= txtJobNumber.ClientID%>").value + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**webmethod**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetCompletionList(ByVal input As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim result As List(Of String) = getJobNumberSuggestions(input)
    Return result
End Function
```

**textbox**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="7" Width="75px" CssClass="autoJobNum" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: First think I would do is put a `console.log` in the success function of the AJAX call and see if your VB method is returning what you expect.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Looks like it's returning an array of correct values: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code in the question works just fine as-is, but removing focus from the textbox (say, to hit continue on a breakpoint in Visual Studio) stops the dropdown from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using autocomplete wrong, thats the way to do it :

```
var submitOK = false;
var searchURL = null;
var checkURL = null;
var autocomplete_fieldname = null;

function autocomplete(fieldName, ajaxURL_getList, ajaxURL_checkInput, formID)
{
    searchURL = ajaxURL_getList;
    checkURL = ajaxURL_checkInput;
    autocomplete_fieldname = fieldName;
    var txtField = $(":text[name='" + fieldName + "']");
    txtField.autocomplete({delay : 50, minLength : 1, search : search, source : searchURL + txtField.val()});
    $("form#" + formID).on("submit", _submit);
}

function search()
{
    //console.log("changed");
    var me = $(":text[name='" + autocomplete_fieldname + "']");
    var val = me.val();
    me.autocomplete("option", "source", searchURL + val);
}

function _submit(evt)
{

    var txtField = $(":text[name='" + autocomplete_fieldname + "']");
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    var xhr = jQuery.getJSON(checkURL + txtField.val() , null, submitResult);
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});

    return submitOK;
}

function submitResult(data)
{
    var txtField = $(":text[name='" + autocomplete_fieldname + "']");

    if(!data || data === "false" || data === false)
    {
        txtField.effect("shake");
        submitOK = false;
    }
    else
    {
        submitOK = true;
    }

}
```

and then set your autocomplete on individual forms and fields like this:

```
autocomplete("MY_FORM_FIELD_NAME", "MY_AJAX_URL?GETLIST=", "MY_AJAX_URL?GETVALUE=", "MY_FORM_ID");
```

this script will reject input which is not found in your data-source - a pretty good validation which also provides powerful autocomplete. You will have to have jQuery UI available but im guessing most people who use jQuery also have jQ-UI :)